# angular-ui-grid load state on controller creation

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I want to load the last state of a ui-grid when the controller is created.
I've set up a plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/cOhLUUABVStfoTH6QVZd?p=preview
In my controller I use a restoreOnLoad function which is called immediately at the end of the controller. I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveState' of undefined because the gridApi is undefined at the time of controller creation.

```
restoreOnLoad = function(){
  //retrieve stateinfo. For simplicity: inline object...
  var stateInfo = {
    "columns": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "visible": true,
            "width": 50,
            "sort": {
                "direction": "asc",
                "priority": 0
            },
            "filters": [
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "M",
            "visible": true,
            "width": 50,
            "sort": {
            },
            "filters": [
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Company",
            "visible": true,
            "width": 200,
            "sort": {
            },
            "filters": [
            ]
        }
    ],
    "scrollFocus": {
    },
    "selection": {
    }
  }
  $scope.gridApi.saveState.restore($scope, stateInfo);
}

restoreOnLoad();
```

Any ideas how to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your restore call is running before the grid's API is registered, so you just need to wait for that to happen.

You can move your `restoreOnLoad()` call to your `onRegisterApi` handler:

```js
vm.gridOptions = {
  onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    restoreOnLoad();
  }
}
```

Comment: if you call restoreOnLoad in the onRegisterApi callback, won't it run *after* the grid rendered.  In other words, that callback doesn't get called until the grid is made visible right....so won't that lead to a double draw?  Draw the grid in the "default" state, then again after restore?